# React-Router Redirect path syntax for path itself AND path with anything following

Tags: redirect, path, react-router

I am redoing some paths in my app and therefore need to preserve the old ones with `Redirect`.I want to change these routes:

1. previous path `/bar` to now redirect to `/foo/bar`.
2. previous path `/bar/fizz` to now redirect to `/foo/bar/fizz`.

Here's what I think should work based on the path syntax docs (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md#path-syntax):

```
<Route path="/" component={...}>
    <Route path="foo" component={...}>
        <Route path="bar" component={...}>
            <Route path="fizz" component={...}/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
    <Redirect from="bar(/*)" to="foo/bar(/*)"/>
</Route>
<Redirect path="*" to="/"/>
```

However this makes only the first desired redirect work, from `/bar` to `/foo/bar`. Trying to go to `/bar/fizz` redirects me to just the root `/`.

If I change the `Redirect` to `<Redirect from="bar/*" to="foo/bar/*"/>` then the opposite is true; only the second desired redirect works, from `/bar/fizz` to `/foo/bar/fizz`. Trying to go to `/bar` redirects me to just the root `/`.

The only way I've gotten it to work is to include two `Redirect`s to cover both scenarios. Is there a more concise way to write this with just one `Redirect`?:

```
<Route path="/" component={...}>
    <Route path="foo" component={...}>
        <Route path="bar" component={...}>
            <Route path="fizz" component={...}/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
    <Redirect from="bar" to="foo/bar"/>
    <Redirect from="bar/*" to="foo/bar/*"/>
</Route>
<Redirect path="*" to="/"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried `<Redirect from="bar*" to="foo/bar*"/>`?

Comment: @jakee YES that's it! Thank you!! Can you submit it as an answer and then I can make it officially the solution?